# Passing cpp options from a header file

Tags: c++, fortran

I am supposed to use a Fortran code for preprocessing. My code is working fine if I write all the define variables (macros) explicitly one by one with cpp

```
cpp -P -traditional -DMPI -DGFORTRAN -DMCT...-I... myfile.F
```

But, I intend to provide them using two header files. One in which all the define variables are mentioned and the second in which the combination of define options are defined again. So I tried,

```
cpp -P -traditional -D'HEADER="myheader.h"'
-D'GLOBAL_DEFS="globaldefinition.h"' -I... myfile.F
```

I don't know why but this is not giving the appropriate output (I only get starting and end lines of my code and not text in between). It seems that the command line does not read the header and global definition file. 
I don't have any idea what's wrong here as I am not familiar with C++.

Here is the example:
When I write

```
cpp -P -traditional -DMPI -DLINUX -DX86_64 -DGFORTRAN
-D'HEADER="myheader.h"' -DMCT_LIB -DMCT_INTERP_OC2AT -DCOUPLING -D'GLOBAL_DEFS="globaldefs.h"' -I/usr/local/include -I../../../bin.dir mct_dir_coupler_params.F
```

I get

```
Module mct_dir_coupler_params
      USE mod_dir_coupler_kinds

      implicit none ! !  Number of coupling models. !
      integer :: N_mctmodels

! !  Sparse matrix weights !
      integer, dimension(:), pointer :: sparse_rows
      integer, dimension(:), pointer :: sparse_cols
      integer, dimension(:), pointer :: dst_grid_imask
      integer, dimension(2) :: src_grid_dims, dst_grid_dims
      real(m8), dimension(:), pointer :: sparse_weights

      TYPE T_DST_GRID
        integer, pointer :: dst_mask(:)
      END TYPE T_DST_GRID
      TYPE (T_DST_GRID), allocatable :: O2A_CPLMASK(:,:)
      TYPE (T_DST_GRID), allocatable :: A2O_CPLMASK(:,:)
      TYPE (T_DST_GRID), allocatable :: W2A_CPLMASK(:,:)

! !  Number of parallel nodes assigned to each model in the coupled !  system. !
      integer :: NnodesATM
      integer :: NnodesWAV
      integer :: NnodesOCN

END Module mct_dir_coupler_params
```

But I want to use

```
cpp -P -traditional -D'HEADER=myheader.h'
-D'GLOBAL_DEFS="globaldefs.h"' -I/usr/local/include -I../../../bin.dir mct_dir_coupler_params.F
```

The output is,

```
  MODULE mct_dir_coupler_params

  END MODULE mct_dir_coupler_params
```

Comment: Are you talking about the fortran code I am using? I have not included any of the two header files in my .F file.

Comment: Why do you expect this command to read any files? All you're doing is define two macros, `HEADER` and `GLOBAL_DEFS`.

Comment: I can not include myheader.h file as it can be changed but I included the global definition file in my Fortran code. It did not work.

Comment: Okay, I got it... Then I should not use HEADER and GLOBAL_DEFS macros, how will I provide the information to the cpp then?

Comment: OK, you need to post a [mcve]. It's not clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is ("*not giving the appropriate output*" and "*did not work*" aren't exactly problem descriptions).

Comment: I meant to say that the command did not read the macros from the header file and so was providing only the starting and end line of my code. It did not provide the content written in between which is completely dependent upon these macros using ifdef condition.

Comment: Stop paraphrasing and post a [mcve], please.

Comment: Check the edit. This was the reason for downvote?

Comment: where are `INCLUDE 'file'` in .F code? nowt quite sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please read the complete post. I have just posted the output. I am trying to get something like the first output.

Comment: Well,for straters, I don't see any C++ here. neither here is any sources, only output. when gfortran runs cpp, it defines varaibles that are relevant to compiler, and cpp starts behave as fortran preprocessor. Then in `-D'HEADER=myheader.h'` you don't have double quotes in second version of command, unclear if that's relevant or not

Comment: I removed that mistakenly, it doesn't make any change to the output. My code has included globaldefs.h at the beginning but not myheader.h

Comment: @nshwal the problem here is that we can't check your source code, see what exactly you've done, and try out our ideas on it. Since my general remarks seem not to be enough, we can't really go on without the possibility of verifying your problem. The link given to you by melpomene states that quite clearly. Best results will be obtained if we can simply copy-paste any code and commands you used and get results.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use

```
#include "myheader.h"
#include "globaldefinition.h"
```

in your `.cpp` or `.h` files?

Edit: this will work: Or, if you are married to the extra macro idea, use

```
#include HEADER
```

Edit: to use C macros in Fortran files, you'll need a compiler directive. For Intel F77, it [seems to be](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/290080) `/Qfpp`, GNU Fortran should invoke cpp automatically for .F files as long as the files including the C-stye directives are included via `#include`, not `INCLUDE` [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/g77_9.html#SEC19)

Comment: `#include HEADER` will work fine. What doesn't work is `#define FOO #include "bar"` followed by `FOO`.

Comment: is there a good reason to use cpp instead of Fortran preprocessors then? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: AFAIK Fortran doesn't have a separate preprocessor.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use these files in the command line, because myheader.h can be changed depending upon the requirement?

Comment: @melpomene GNU Fortran automatically invokes cpp for .F-files, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Preprocessing-and-conditional-compilation.html